# power supply - MOSFET control

Tags: power-supply

How to control a MOSFET to conduct only when the voltage is above a certain value (400V)? What gate drivers are dedicated to this application? The MOSFET is unlikely to be controlled by a Zener diode.[image]

Comment: Why did you delete the text of your previous related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/664811/revisions. A comment you made on that question makes me think this is a duplicate posting: *How to control the MOSFET to conduct at 400V on C1?*. However, you never answered the queries raised.